# ASP.NET Core app to Linux on Azure App Service

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, docker, asp.net-core

I'm deploying the Linux based ASP.NET core app using Azure Web App, exactly same thing follow which mention in [this blog post](https://montemagno.com/aspnet-core-azure-linux-app-service-deployment/).

But when i accessing the hosted URL getting error - **Service Unavailable**

Not sure what is causing the issue to run application.

Here is log info which i get from kudu services.

> 2018-01-04 12:20:05.716 ERROR - Container dotnetlinuxapp_1 for site dotnetlinuxapp has exited, failing site start
>   2018-01-04 12:20:18.304 INFO  - Starting container for site
>   2018-01-04 12:20:18.305 INFO  - docker run -d -p 24936:8080 --name dotnetlinuxapp_1 -e WEBSITE_SITE_NAME=DotNetLinuxApp -e WEBSITE_AUTH_ENABLED=False -e WEBSITE_ROLE_INSTANCE_ID=0 -e WEBSITE_INSTANCE_ID=fdcd5b5339be6bb353a84764edb2155ae6bb8d934d2d889b883ef65bcb729a44 -e HTTP_LOGGING_ENABLED=1 appsvc/dotnetcore:1.1.2_1709181723 /home/site/wwwroot/Meetup.Web.dll 
>   2018-01-04 12:20:19.646 ERROR - Container dotnetlinuxapp_1 for site dotnetlinuxapp has exited, failing site start

Comment: Sounds like there's something wrong with the docker image. Not enough here to diagnose, though.

Comment: @ChrisPratt, this is how i set the path for docker container in Webapp - https://pasteboard.co/H1nexaM.png and rest will manage by webapp

Comment: Have you checked this similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45940045/azure-app-service-docker-container-service-unavailable)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have reviewed your issue and found that you are referring blog have not latest information and cause of that you are facing this issue.

Please append "dotnet " in starting of text which you are entering into startup file. "dotnet" it will take as command. so your startup file become like...

> dotnet /home/site/wwwroot/{yourDLLName}.dll

[image]

Definitely it will resolve your issue, Cheers !

Hope This Helps !

Comment: OMG! You have no idea how happy i am with your answer!! I would never figure this out, i thought the 404 in my Azure app API was related to problems with my routes or deploy issues. I'm using Core 2.0 and it worked!!! Thanks man

Comment: For .NET 5 on lInux, this fix works as well but with a slightly different startup cmd: dotnet <dll name>.dll